# Advanced chroma key code samples

Tags: actionscript-3, algorithm, language-agnostic, chromakey, pixel-bender

I'm working on an application that needs to key out the background from an image taken by a webcam in front of a green screen. I figured this would be a very common task, but to my surprise i'm having trouble finding code samples for anything more advanced than a simple color-threshold and those do not quite cut it quality wise.

I've found a few pdf-papers, but I'm having trouble translating these rather high concepts into actual implementations, I'd much rather look at some code.

Focus here is on quality, having a second or more of processing time is not a problem.
I will be using actionscript 3 (and possibly pixel bender) to implement this, but I'll happily look at other languages aswell.

If you have any good samples doing this, the whole process or parts, please do post them!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no high requirement for chromakey quality, maybe this(http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000615.php) will be okay.
But for high quality video( i.e, 720*576 video ), it is not easy job.
I have spent a lot time to research high quality chromakey algorithm, finally I have figured out one algorithm(implemented with c/c++) for real time video,which can be used in none-linear video editing system as plugin or standalone application. 
I put some demo static images to show at voicethread.com websites, everyone can comment with text, or voice there.
http://voicethread.com/share/801789/